# Domain's email account with phpMailer and Gmail

Tags: php, email, gmail, phpmailer

Two scenarios:

1. I recently downloaded the `phpMailer` and added it to my `public_html` folder.
2. I add my domain's email accounts to my gmail account.

Two problems:

- When sending emails (domain's email account) using `phpMailer` and Gmail, and when the recipient received it, the red question mark is appearing instead of the Gmail's default profile photo.

What do I need to do to solve this? I searched about in `phpMailer` that I need some `DKIM` and `SPF` keys or something.

Answer (score 1):

Your message is not authenticated, you must set a SPF configuration this is a TXT record on your domain (envelope). For Example "v=spf1 ip4:204.200.197.197 -all" means the ip 204.200.197.197 is allowed to send mails over your domain.

more information to gmail red question mark
https://support.google.com/mail/answer/180707?vid=0-1292648286207-1480402255906&hl=en

more informations to spf records
http://www.openspf.org/FAQ/Examples

Comment: How do I set it? I am only using a shared hosting plan.

Comment: Gmail preferred DKIM.

Comment: Contact your hoster, he can help set this configuration

Comment: They said, I should just ignore and wait til' they solve this.